# LVS Load Balancer Not Getting Response

Tags: load-balancing, linux-networking, lvs

I am trying to learn IPVS/LVS and am a bit stuck.  The director seems to be configured properly, with packets coming in, but packets are not being forwarded to the backend servers.  Any tips on what is missing?  I was under the impression a load balancer could be achieved without iptables and would like to achieve that.

**Director Host**

```
root@ip-172-31-16-196:/home/ubuntu# cat  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

root@ip-172-31-16-196:/home/ubuntu# ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 06:a0:5b:48:1b:f5
              inet addr:172.31.16.196  Bcast:172.31.31.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::4a0:5bff:fe48:1bf5/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
              RX packets:4211 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:3692 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:416625 (416.6 KB)  TX bytes:406446 (406.4 KB)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
              RX bytes:12776 (12.7 KB)  TX bytes:12776 (12.7 KB)

root@ip-172-31-16-196:/home/ubuntu# ipvsadm -Ln
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  172.31.16.196:80 rr
  -> 172.31.16.195:80             Masq    1      0          0

root@ip-172-31-16-196:/home/ubuntu# ipvsadm -Ln --stats
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port               Conns   InPkts  OutPkts  InBytes OutBytes
  -> RemoteAddress:Port
TCP  172.31.16.196:80                   23      122        0     6436        0
  -> 172.31.16.195:80                   23      122        0     6436        0

root@ip-172-31-16-196:/home/ubuntu# curl 172.31.16.195-vv
* Rebuilt URL to: 172.31.16.195/
*   Trying 172.31.16.195...
* Connected to 172.31.16.195 (172.31.16.195) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.31.16.195
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.12
< Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 04:59:04 GMT
< Content-type: text/html
< Content-Length: 26
< Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 00:58:21 GMT
<
From server 172.31.16.195
* Closing connection 0

# Show the public IP of this host
root@ip-172-31-16-196:/home/ubuntu# wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -
52.15.105.107
```

**Backend Server**

```
root@ip-172-31-16-195:/home/ubuntu# netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2444/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1221/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1221/sshd

root@ip-172-31-16-195:/home/ubuntu# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**From Remote Client**

```
# Hitting the public IP
$ curl -vvv http://52.15.105.107/
*   Trying 52.15.105.107...
* Connected to 52.15.105.107 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 52.15.105.107
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
< Server: ScanSafe
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 05:40:50 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 1664
< X-ScanSafe-Error: ERR_CONNECT_FAIL 110
< Keep-Alive: 60
< Via: HTTP/1.1 proxy10829
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-posting from my LVS mailing list response:

Usually for MASQ/NAT mode the real server would be in a different
subnet with the LVS server set as the default gateway.

If you want to do one-arm i.e. same subnet MASQ then the test client
needs to be in a separate subnet OR you need to have special routing
rules on the real (backend) server.

https://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/load-balancing-methods

Comment: I just remembered that you will also need to disable the source and destination checks on the load balancer:

Disable the source / Destination check on the instance in AWS. To do this go to the EC2 console and select your load balancer instance. Then select “Actions > Network > Change source/Dest. check” and Disable this option. Doing so enables the instance to receive traffic which has a destination IP it does not own.

https://loadbalancer.org/blog/transparent-load-balancing-with-haproxy-on-amazon-ec2